# For loop: How to print the remaining sequence?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a vector:

```
vector <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

And I want to print the following:

```
[1] A then B and C
[1] B then A and C
[1] C then A and B
```

I have been working with a for loop. However, I can't figure out how to print the sequence seperated by 'and'?

```
for(i in vector){ 
  print(paste(i, "then", XXX))
}
```

I guess something needs to added where I wrote XXX?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` with `collapse = " then "` and reorder `vector` using `[` in your `for` loop.

```
for(i in seq_along(vector)) { 
  print(paste0(vector[i], " then ", paste(vector[-i], collapse = " and ")))
}
#[1] "A then B and C"
#[1] "B then A and C"
#[1] "C then A and B"
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved half of the problem! I need to look more into seq_along - never head about it! However, I would like to change the last `then` to `and`, e.g. `"A then B and C`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry have over-read that. Hope the output is now OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdiff` to find the remaining vector and then `paste` with `collapse=` to put that whole vector together into some text:

```
for(i in vector){ 
  remaining.elements.vector <- setdiff(vector, i)
  remaining.elements.text <- paste(remaining.elements.vector, collapse=' and ')
  print(paste(i, "then", remaining.elements.text))
}
```